# Error with Inheritance and TypeScript: X is not a constructor function type

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript

I have this super class that I want two other classes to inherit from. The classes are listed below. When I compile, the two classes trying to inherit complain about the superclass (the give the same error):
"[class file path (in this case A)] is not a constructor function type"

A.ts

```
export class A
{
    //private fields...

    constructor(username: string, password: string, firstName: string,
        lastName: string, accountType: string) 
    {
        // initialisation
    }
}
```

B.ts

```
import A = require('./A);
export class B extends A
{
    constructor(username: string, password: string, firstName: string,
        lastName: string, accountType: string) 
    {
        super(username, password, firstName, lastName, accountType);
    }
}
```

C.ts

```
import A = require('./A );
export class C extends A
{
    constructor(username: string, password: string, firstName: string,
        lastName: string, accountType: string) 
    {
        super(username, password, firstName, lastName, accountType);
    }
}
```

This is pretty simple, and yet Class C and B cannot compile. All the examples I have seen online do not have any other syntax for writing these classes/ constructor. I am trying to follow convention, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Is the documentation for the super() constructor call wrong as well? (in my subclasses). I followed the same procedure, but its also stating that my supplied parameters are wrong.

Comment: Your constructors look fine, what's the actual error?

Comment: error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: @maria: You must have edited your files, because the ones above work for me. Probably just a small typo somewhere.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Replace

```
import A = require('./A');
```

with

```
import { A } from './A';
```

or

```
import moduleA = require('./A');

export class B extends moduleA.A {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Where is `import...from` documented? I don't see it anywhere in http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules.

Comment: The handbook hasn't been updated in quite a while, I don't think it's wrong as such, but there are newer and better ways of doing some things that aren't mentioned in there. I suggest reading https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript once you've familiarized yourself with the contents of the handbook.

Comment: @VadimMacagon Will do. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how the import style used in the handbook would be used.